# Adjectif possessif avec « on »

Tags: possessif

Je me demande comment on utilise les adjectifs possessifs à la forme impersonnelle. Est-ce que c'est correct de dire :

> On devrait rester prudent quel que soit son courage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La règle générale est que lorsque le possesseur est indéterminé on emploie  un adjectif possessif de la troisième personne *son* ou *sa*.

Exemple cité par [Grevisse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grevisse) :

> On ne sent vraiment bien que sa peine. (La Bruyère)

Cependant, précise, Grevisse,

> quand la clarté le demande, on emploie *nos*, (si le locuteur se met dans la collectivité : d'autres + moi) ─ ou *vos* (si le locuteur s'efface et ne se met pas dans la collectivité).

Deux exemples cités par Grevisse :

> - On ressent tous les jours que cette violence excite nos désirs (Bossuet)
> - On ne refuse pas le bonheur quand il frappe à votre porte. (A. Chamson)

Pour la phrase proposée dans la question je dirais spontanément :

> On devrait rester prudent quel que soit son courage.

car je ne la remarque est générale, c'est un peu comme un dicton et il n'y a pas besoin de clarification.

Imaginons deux situations :

- [Un guide touristique](http://www.routard.com/hotel/la_maison_du_lagon_1_29248.htm#37057) :

  > L'hôtel ne dispose pas de restaurant mais **on peut apporter son panier repas** et manger sur sa terrasse ou dans le jardin.
- Je pars en randonnée avec des amis et nous nous posons la question du repas. Je peux dire :

  > On pourrait prendre notre panier repas.

  aussi bien que :

  > On pourrait prendre son panier repas.

Comment: Hyper util ! Merci !

Comment: Le dernier exemple est un peu étrange quand même. On a l'impression qu'on envisage de voler le panier de quelqu'un. On s'attendrait plutôt à ce que la phrase commence par « chacun ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Dans ce contexte, tu crois ? On est entre amis, on se comprend. La règle est la même avec chacun, ça marcherait, mais on n'est pas obligé de prendre un panier repas par personne. C'est un concept le panier repas, on peut en avoir un pour 2 ou 3. On peut aussi décider dans la suite de la discussion qu'untel prendra les hors-d’œuvre, untel les boissons, untel le dessert, etc...  Avec chacun ça veut dire que chacun prend avec lui ce qu'il va manger sans idée de partage.

Comment: Oui c'est vrai que le sens est différent. Et à la réflexion, il me semble avoir entendu des gens parler comme ça (avec « son » plutôt que « nous », alors que le pronom renvoie à un ensemble défini de personnes). Il y a probablement des tendances régionales.

Answer (score 2):

Dans cette phrase, comme le *on* remplace en réalité un *nous*, je dirai plutôt :

> On devrait rester prudent quel que soit notre courage.

Comment: Merci! Maintenant c'est clair.

Comment: Ce serait bien de traiter plus que ce cas particulier, la question paraissait générale.